# ArrayList de Objetos + Herança

Tags: java, lista, herança

Tudo bem pessoal estou com uma dúvida sobre herança, por exemplo:

```
    List<Carros> carros = new ArrayList<>();
    Chevete chevete = new Chevete();
    chevete.acelerarMuito(); //Até aqui ok
    carros.add(chevete);//Adicionando chevete numa lista de carros
    carros.get(0).??? //Não consigo mais usar o método acelerar
```

Como proceder? A minha intenção é ter uma List com objetos herdados, mas preciso usar os métodos específicos de cada um acessando pelo .get(index)

Não quero criar uma List para cada modelo de carro.
Suponha que o método acelerarMuito so existe no chevete, por isso não criei na classe Carro.

Comment: Olha, se bem entendi, você quer guardar subtipos na mesma lista e acessar métodos exclusivos deles a partir da lista. Isso irá te dar problema! A partir do momento que você generaliza o tipo da lista, não há como garantir se o objeto Carro é Chevete, Corsa, ou seja lá o que for. Se precisa de mais especifico, torne o método comum a todos, na superclasse. Uma solução, bem porca aliás, seria checar se o objeto atual acessado é uma instância de chevete, e em caso positivo, forçar o cast, mas não me recordo bem agora se o java permitirá isso.

Comment: `Carros` pode ser uma interface com os métodos que você quer disponibilizar de forma genérica. Na classe `Chevete` você implementa a interface.

Answer (score 0):

Tem 2 formas de se fazer isso. 
A classe Carros possui o metodo `acelerar()` astrato possuindo implementação em cada modelo de carro:

```
public abstract class Carro {
   public abstract void acelerar();
}
```

Ou você precisará de um cast para o modelo específico de veículo ao utilizar o método:

```
if (carros.get(0) instanceof Chevete) {
   ((Chevete)carros.get(0)).acelerar();
}
```

Como todo carro acelera, a primeira abordagem faz mais sentido nesse exemplo, mas podem haver métodos específicos de um determinado modelo, aí a segunda se aplica.

Comment: `preciso usar os métodos específicos de cada um acessando pelo .get(index)` -  acho que você não leu este trecho da pergunta.

Comment: Percebi sim, por isso sugeri a segunda abordagem com o cast `((Chevete)carros.get(0)).acelerar();`

Comment: O cast neste caso não é garantido, haja visto que ele mesmo disse que guardará subtipos diferentes na lista.

Comment: Ele teria que garantir o tipo específico através de um `if (carros.get(0) instanceof Chevete)` para poder usar o cast sem riscos. Do contrário apenas utilizando o método na superclasse.

Comment: Na verdade não. Por meio de uma abordagem por interfaces da pra fazer isso. mas foge ao escopo da duvida.

Comment: Certamente interfaces fazem sentido pois seria possível definir metodos de um conjunto de modelos, como CarrosEsportivos ou algo do genero. Mas ainda assim cairia no problema de um List genérico e seria necessário um cast para a interface para os métodos poderem ser utilizados.